# How to deploy web application as a child/sub application in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I want to deploy one web application(react) in the child folder of another application in Azure. In other words, I want to deploy one application as a subdomain of main application.

For example, we can add application inside the website in IIS:

[image]

In this example, url of test_emc is: http://localhost:81/ and url of its child application i.e. App is: http://localhost:81/App/. This child application works as a separate application but share the domain only.

How can I do this for Azure App Service? I have deployed my web application in Azure and its url is:

https://test-features.azurewebsites.net/

now inside this, I want to deploy one more application(react) as a sub application. Its url should be like:

https://test-features.azurewebsites.net/react/

How can I do this?

Comment: I have looked into it and it i will definitely work for ASP.Net web application. But in my case, chid application is in react. So I am not sure how to deploy it in azure virtual directly as I am deployed it from  VS Code extension AZURE: APP SERVICE where I see app services only.

Comment: Try deploying your React app using FTP